# Blocking only outgoing sound

Tags: acoustics, material-science

Is there a one-way, Faraday Cage like implementation for sound signals i.e. blocking only outbound sound?

I mean a case like the car driver can hear the sound outside, but the loud and awful music of his radio is not let out by some material.

Answer (score 3):

You are basically asking if acoustic diodes exist which allow sound to move in one direction, but not the opposite.  Yes, such devices do exist:
https://physics.aps.org/synopsis-for/10.1103/PhysRevLett.106.084301
and
https://phys.org/news/2015-09-one-way-tunnel-acoustic.html

Comment: Good point for the 'acoustic diode' concept. Yet, I'm not sure if it can deal with a car windows open.